# Creating hierarchical data and adding it to a TreeTableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, treetableview

I just got into programming and I am writing a program in java for counting votes using Single Transferable Vote. I have my input data in an Excel file looking like this:

[image: this]

where the name of the candidate is mapped to the number under it in a `HashTable` and every row below row 2 represents one voters preferences from left to right.

I want to add the names and votes in a `TreeTableView` looking something like this:

[image: this].

Where each candidate is a root for their second preferences, each second preference is a root for the third preferences, each third preference is a root for the fourth preferences and so on.

I am using the `apache.poi` library to use the Excel files. I am looking for tips on how to represent the hierarchical data from the sheet and how to add it to the `TreeTabeView`. How could I do this?

Sorry if this is a noob question. I am not very familiar with how to use hierarchical data. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a item class with 2 properties

- candidate
- vote count

would do the trick (=one property per column). E.g.

```
public class VoteEntry {

    // candidate INDEX
    private final IntegerProperty candidate;

    private final IntegerProperty voteCount;

    public VoteEntry(int candidate, int count) {
        this.voteCount = new SimpleIntegerProperty(count);
        this.candidate = new SimpleIntegerProperty(candidate);
    }

    public final int getCandidate() {
        return this.candidate.get();
    }

    public final void setCandidate(int value) {
        this.candidate.set(value);
    }

    public final IntegerProperty candidateProperty() {
        return this.candidate;
    }

    public final int getVoteCount() {
        return this.voteCount.get();
    }

    public final void setVoteCount(int value) {
        this.voteCount.set(value);
    }

    public final IntegerProperty voteCountProperty() {
        return this.voteCount;
    }

}
```

You could group the votes to smaller and smaller subgroups to create the `TreeItem` hierarchy:

```
private final List<int[]> votes = new ArrayList<>();

private void addVote(int... preferences) {
    // convert to array of candidate indices sorted descendingly by preference
    int[] votes = new int[preferences.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < preferences.length; i++) {
        votes[preferences[i] - 1] = i;
    }
    this.votes.add(votes);
}

private static void createHierarchy(TreeItem<VoteEntry> parent, List<int[]> votes, int index) {
    int max = votes.stream().mapToInt(a -> a.length).max().getAsInt();
    if (max > index) {
        // group by candidate
        Map<Integer, List<int[]>> groups = votes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.length > index ? a[index] : -1));
        groups.forEach((candidate, vts) -> {
            if (candidate != -1) {
                VoteEntry entry = new VoteEntry(candidate, vts.size());
                TreeItem<VoteEntry> item = new TreeItem<>(entry);
                parent.getChildren().add(item);
                createHierarchy(item, vts, index + 1);
            }
        });

        // sort by candidate
        parent.getChildren().sort(Comparator.comparingInt(ti -> ti.getValue().getCandidate()));
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    addVote(1, 2, 3, 4);
    addVote(4, 3, 2, 1);
    addVote(1, 3, 2, 4);
    addVote(2, 1, 4, 3);
    addVote(2, 4, 3, 1);
    addVote(2, 1, 3, 4);
    // ...

    ObservableList<String> candidateNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Candidate 1",
            "Candidate 2",
            "Candidate 3",
            "Candidate 4"
            );

    TreeItem<VoteEntry> root = new TreeItem<>();
    createHierarchy(root, votes, 0);

    TreeTableView<VoteEntry> view = new TreeTableView<>(root);
    view.setShowRoot(false);

    TreeTableColumn<VoteEntry, String> candidateColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("candidate");
    candidateColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> Bindings.valueAt(candidateNames, data.getValue().getValue().candidateProperty()));

    TreeTableColumn<VoteEntry, Integer> votesColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("votes");
    votesColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("voteCount"));

    view.getColumns().addAll(candidateColumn, votesColumn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(view);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that the recursive approach only works for a limited amount of candidates (stackoverflows). But it should work for reasonable candidate numbers (a user wouldn't want to extend hundreds of items...).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked but i noticed one problem. The conversion of the int... prefrences to an array didn't work properly. Fixed it by changing the code inside the for loop to "votes[i] = preferences[i]-1;".